# Should you follow your passion when choosing a job? What are the benefits and downsides?

Tags: job-search

One of the things we are advised to do when choosing a degree is to think about what we are passionate about and I did that and chose computer science. But how much does that apply to choosing a job? Should you choose a job based on your passions?

Comment: I'm passionate about sitting around doing nothing.... so it works out for some, not for others.

Comment: This is far too broad a question to be On-Topic but here's some advice anyway: You should pick a career that sits at the intersection of 3 things: What you're good at. What you find interesting/engaging. What is valued by other people. *Passion* is great, but mere interest/engagement is more than enough.

Comment: If you're lucky enough to find a job that meets your expectations, I don't think there will be a downside except from working too much and forgetting that you have a life. But you might as unlucky as I am, and although you'll find a job that meets your degree, it might not meet your expectations, and the downside will be disappointment and lack of interest. The good thing about life is even if you don't like your job, you can follow your passion in your free time.

Comment: @Kaz at some point money also enters into play...

Comment: @laurent That was what I meant by “valued by other people”. Or else they wouldn’t be willing to pay for it.

Comment: "Find a job that is your passion and you will not have a passion anymore and wil work 16 hours a day because you will feel you're never at work"

Answer (score 7):

Although you often hear that one should follow his/her passion when choosing a profession, it actually is a pretty stupid advice in most cases. I also think the reasons why it is a stupid advice are pretty straightforward but I will tell them anyway.

The sad reality is that a lot of people are passionate about something for which there are very little (paying) jobs available. The most extreme examples of such passion-jobs are professional artist, actor/actress, writer or athlete. Although many people dream/try to become one of those, unfortunately more than 99.99 percent of them will fail at it.

Another reason is that something may be your passion when you do it for a hobby, for example cooking. However if you have to do it for 8 to 10 hours a day in a high-pressure restaurant it might not be as fun anymore.

So when should you choose a job based on your passions?

- If your passion is actually something marketable, like for example computer science.
- If you are rich and don't need a job to support yourself, but just to keep yourself busy.
- If you are pretty sure that the hobby you do for a few hours a week keeps being fun if you do it for 40 hours or more in a professional environment.

If those points do not apply to you, I think it's best to settle for something a bit less than your passion.

Comment: Yep. Hobbies are fun because you only do them when you feel like it, in whatever way you feel like doing it. When it’s a job and you have to do it when you’re told to, in the way you’re told to, you may quickly discover it’s the exact opposite of enjoyable.

Comment: Just as an example, I was sent to Hawaii on a crash development effort. I wound up doing 14 hour work days for weeks. I got no time on the beach. I was so glad to get back to the mainland so that I could do shorter work days. Being sent to a dream vacation spot for "work your ass off" effort is no vacation. Having to work on a hobby under extreme time pressure makes the hobby no fun.

Answer (score 3):

Adding to Kaz's comment that you should chose a career at the intersection of what you're good at, what you find interesting/engaging and what is valued by other people:

It really depends on your personality. I've had several totally different jobs in my life (language-related, IT-related, business-related) and can honesty said I loved every of them. I get hooked on things easily and there are few topics I don't find interesting. On the other hand, what is extremely important to me is some degree of trust from my manager, lack of micromanagement and too much politics, and ability to develop my skills further and to challenge myself in every area I work in. It's more "the how" than "the what" of the profession.

So in my case, the passion doesn't matter cause I will develop it anyway.

There are people however, who can't imagine working with technology or similar. For them, that's the priority.

You should strive to get to know yourself: your strengths and weaknesses and priorities. Then take them into consideration while choosing your profession and employers.

Answer (score 0):

The reality is, most people never find their passion. It's a silly mantra that gets thrown about. When people say "passion" it's often used as a buzz word to replace the word interest.

The idea is that if you enjoy what you do, then it wont be a mundane boring job that you do until retirement. However, **just because it's your passion, doesn't mean you'll like doing it as a job.**

A job is chosen based on:

1. Can you get hired/paid to do it
2. Does it pay enough to support your lifestyle

If you find it fun or interesting, that's a bonus. 100% aim for a job you find interesting, but not everyone has that luxury.

Chances are if you're passionate or interested about something, you probably study it in your own time. As a result it's probably the area you have most knowledge in, so makes sense to get a job doing it, if it pays well.

Positives:

- You will gain a deep knowledge of a field you're interested (passionate) about
- You may enjoy your work

Negatives:

- You may hate it and end up resenting your passion
- You may become a workaholic
- Unless you start your own company you'll be pursuing your passion under some else's dictatorship

I'll give you a better mantra: "follow your interests so you can discover your passion"

IE. Ideally you should get a job that pays well, and that you think sounds interesting. And don't forget, you can change your career path whenever you like.